# How to populate default values of fields while creating issues in JIRA using jira-plugin?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am working on jira-plugin to create issues in JIRA. I am using the method - [create(user,createValidationResult)](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/6.2.7/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/IssueService.html#create(com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User,%20com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService.CreateValidationResult)) to create issue.

I need to give values of mandatory fields while creating.

I want to give the default values of fields while creating. (The default values are the ones which are configured during the creation of these in JIRA)

I have found the below methods

1. method [populateDefaults](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/6.2.7/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/OrderableField.html#populateDefaults(java.util.Map,%20com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue))
2. method [getDefaultValue](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/6.2.7/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/OrderableField.html#getDefaultValue(com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue))

But both the methods require [Issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/6.2.7/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html)- parameter which is not yet created as I need to create the issue after setting default values

Please let me know how to set the values for these fields. These fields are added using method [addCustomFieldValue](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/6.2.7/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueInputParameters.html#addCustomFieldValue(java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.String...)) in the class  [IssueInputParameters](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/6.2.7/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueInputParameters.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself : (This works perfectly)

Use the below method :

```
    IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = 
                                    issueService.newIssueInputParameters();

    issueInputParameters.setApplyDefaultValuesWhenParameterNotProvided(true);

    IssueService.CreateValidationResult createValidationResult = 
                         issueService.validateCreate(user, issueInputParameters);

    issueService.create(user,createValidationResult);
```

Note : In the above code **'issueService'** is an object of IssueService.